# Title with different header only first page

Tags: tables, header-footer

how do I have different headings as in the figure below.

[image: header from first page]

[image: header from others pages]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You should post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805)

Comment: For a single page, it is easier to overlay the margins than change them.  Use \raisebox in the first line of text together with \thispagestyle{empty} or \thispagestyle{plain}.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general scheme you will need to modify
depending on the type of document (double-sided, single-sided), the size of the tables in the headers, and other specific aspects.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{first}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\tabfirst}
}
\fancypagestyle{other}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\vbox{\tabother}}
}

\def\tabfirst{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
  \hline
        xxx                & xxx & xxx\\\hline  
  \multirow{3}{3cm}{xxx}   & xxx & xxx\\\cline{3-3}
                           & xxx & xxx\\\cline{3-3}
                           & xxx & xxx\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\def\tabother{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{3cm}{xxx}   & xxx\\\cline{2-2}
                           & xxx\\\cline{2-2}
                           & xxx\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{first}

\section{Heading for the first page}

\clearpage 

\pagestyle{other}

\section{Heading for the other pages}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `\pagestyle{other}` before `\begin{document}` and replace `\pagestyle{first}` by `\thispagestyle{first}`. Then you can remove `\clearpage\pagestyle{other}` in the document.

Comment: how do I eliminate the space ("hole") above the text?

Comment: @Werner 

How can I eliminate the space or 'hole' appeared in place the first row from the table?

Comment: @Ivan

How can I eliminate the space or 'hole' appeared in place the first row from the table?

Comment: Look at the code now. I added `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to delete the rule in the headers and I put `\tabother` inside a `\vbox` so that it the table is top aligned